# translating a command line curl into php

Tags: php, curl, header

i am not very curl savvy was wondering if anyone could help me turn the following into php:

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"tester":{"email":"justin@prefinery.com","status":"applied","profile":{"first_name": "Justin", "last_name": "Britten"},"responses":{"response":[{"question_id":"23874", "answer":"a text response"},{"question_id":"23871", "answer":"1"},{"question_id":"23872", "answer":"0,2"},{"question_id":"23873", "answer":"9"}]}}}' https://account.prefinery.com/api/v2/betas/1/testers.json?api_key=secret`

if you know of a good curl tutorial would also be great help.

Comment: Well they pretty much have equal analogs. Look at the `manpage` for curl and not what options you are using, then compare with the [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) docs to see the php equiv.

Comment: would you mind supplying a link to those pages ? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: there is a link in the comment...

Comment: I linked to to the curl_setopt docs already... jsut clck that word. As for the mangpage jsut type `man curl` on the commandline.

Comment: ah did not realize the that was a link. thanks will read through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
 $ch = curl_init();
            $json = '{"tester":{"email":"justin@prefinery.com","status":"applied","profile":{"first_name": "Justin", "last_name": "Britten"},"responses":{"response":[{"question_id":"23874", "answer":"a text response"},{"question_id":"23871", "answer":"1"},{"question_id":"23872", "answer":"0,2"},{"question_id":"23873", "answer":"9"}]}}}';
            $url = 'https://account.prefinery.com/api/v2/betas/1/testers.json?api_key=secret';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
```